# Why are @@, @!, @, etc. not interpolated in strings?

Tags: perl

First, please note that I ask this question out of curiosity, and I'm aware that using variable names like `@@` is probably not a good idea.

When using doubles quotes (or `qq` operator), scalars and arrays are interpolated :

```
$v = 5;
say "$v"; # prints: 5
$@ = 6;
say "$@"; # prints: 6
@a = (1,2);
say "@a"; # prints: 1 2
```

Yet, with array names of the form `@`+*special char* like `@@`, `@!`, `@,`, `@%`, `@;` etc, the array isn't interpolated :

```
@; = (1,2);
say "@;"; # prints nothing
say @; ; # prints: 1 2
```

So here is my question : does anyone knows why such arrays aren't interpolated? Is it documented anywhere?

I couldn't find any information or documentation about that. There are too many articles/posts on google (or SO) about the basics of interpolation, so maybe the answer was just hidden in one of them, or at the 10th page of results..

*If you wonder why I could need variable names like those :*

- The `-n` (and `-p` for that matter) flag adds a semicolon `;` at the end of the code (I'm not sure it works on every version of perl though). So I can make this program `perl -nE 'push@a,1;say"@a"}{say@a'` shorter by doing instead  `perl -nE 'push@;,1;say"@;"}{say@'`, because that last `;` convert `say@` to `say@;`. Well, actually I can't do that because `@;` isn't interpolated in double quotes. It won't be useful every day of course, but in some golfing challenges, why not!
- It can be useful to obfuscate some code. (whether obfuscation is useful or not is another debate!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't tell you why, but this restriction comes from code in `toke.c` that goes back to perl 5.000 (1994!). My best guess is that it's because Perl doesn't use any built-in array punctuation variables (except for `@-` and `@+`, added in 5.6 (2000)).

The code in `S_scan_const` only interprets `@` as the start of an array if the following character is

- a word character (e.g. `@x`, `@_`, `@1`), or
- a `:` (e.g. `@::foo`), or
- a `'` (e.g. `@'foo` (this is the old syntax for `::`)), or
- a `{` (e.g. `@{foo}`), or
- a `$` (e.g. `@$foo`), or
- a `+` or `-` (the arrays `@+` and `@-`), but not in regexes.

As you can see, the only punctuation arrays that are supported are `@-` and `@+`, and even then not inside a regex. Initially no punctuation arrays were supported; `@-` and `@+` were special-cased in 2000. (The exception in regex patterns was added to make `/[\c@-\c_]/` work; it used to interpolate `@-` first.)

There is a workaround: Because `@{` is treated as the start of an array variable, the syntax `"@{;}"` works (but that doesn't help your golf code because it makes the code longer).

Comment: Yet `say @@;` (or any of the others) prints just fine, so it recognizes the array. Further, the grammar description in `perldata` does not seem to exclude punctuation -- and I couldn't find a distinction between what may follow the sigil `$` vs the sigil `@`. Also, so does `say for @!;` work fine.

Comment: @zdim `say @@` works because the lexer treats things differently when it's inside a double-quoted string. The code melpomene refers to is [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/toke.c#L3220). As you can see, it's hard-coded to look for only certain characters after `@` when doing string interpolation.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Ah, thank you! I didn't get it that it's the interpolation code -- and was wondering.  Then I'd call it ... a bug? The fact that it differs. I don't see a rationale for it.

Answer (score 6):

Perl's documentation says that the result is "not strictly predictable".

The following, from `perldoc perlop` (Perl 5.22.1), refers to interpolation of scalars. I presume it applies equally to arrays.

> Note also that the interpolation code needs to make a decision on
>   where the interpolated scalar ends. For instance, whether
>   `"a $x -> {c}"` really means:
>
> ```
> "a " . $x . " -> {c}";
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> "a " . $x -> {c};
> ```
>
> Most of the time, the longest possible text that does not include
>   spaces between components and which contains matching braces or
>   brackets. because the outcome may be determined by voting based on
>   heuristic estimators, the result is not strictly predictable.
>   Fortunately, it's usually correct for ambiguous cases.

Comment: From what I could tell this relates to the delimiters, `{}` and such. In other words, where the variable to interpolate starts and ends.  It doesn't talk about recognizing the variable _name_.  It's really puzzling.

Answer (score 3):

Some things are just because "Larry coded it that way".  Or as I used to say in class, "It works the way you think, provided you think like Larry thinks", sometimes adding "and it's my job to teach you how Larry thinks."